# Deploying to smart device with visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-ce

There is an deployment feature in visual studio 2008 for smart device projects. What versions of os can be targeted with this deployment method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2008 supports projects for .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and 3.5 on Windows CE and Windows Mobile 5. However, in my experience, deployment works also on other versions, as long as the device supports the 2.0 or 3.5 version of the Compact Framework (the required version of the CF will be installed automatically by VS 2008).

What I mean is: While you target the Windows Mobile 5 with a Compact Framework 3.5 project, you can still connect a device that has Windows Mobile 6.5 installed and the project will be deployed alright.

You may have problems deploying projects for Windows CE to Windows Mobile devices or vice versa, but in general, it should work.

This, however, does not seem to be true for Windows Phone 7, as there is not only a specialized VS 2010 version for Windows Phone, but also "real" compact framework applications can no longer be deployed to Windows Phone devices.